# Cos'è "un'uniforme di regime"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> Guardo la folla allegra e vociante, e m'immedesimo nel fastidio che deve provare la nostra ospite da quando un numero sempre crescente dei suoi invitati ha preso il vizio di indossare, al posto del frac, una lugubre **uniforme di regime**.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "uniforme di regime". Si tratta forse di un'uniforme militare?

Comment: Quando si svolge l'azione del romanzo? Se fosse durante il fascismo, potrebbe essere l'[orbace](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/orbace/), la divisa del Partito Nazionale Fascista, come per esempio [qualcosa del genere](http://uniformisgaggero.altervista.org/index.php?pagina=ItalianiInCamiciaNera&numpag=1&subpag=07&numarr=9). In rete troverai molto, se ti interessa, anche se vari siti sono di lugubri nostalgici.

Comment: @DaG: Accade negli anni 1930.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visto che l'azione del romanzo si svolge negli anni Trenta, e quindi durante il fascismo, probabilmente si tratta del cosiddetto [orbace](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/orbace/), la divisa del Partito Nazionale Fascista, come per esempio qualcosa del genere:

[image: Manichino in camicia nera]

<sup>[Fonte](http://uniformisgaggero.altervista.org/index.php?pagina=ItalianiInCamiciaNera&numpag=1&subpag=07&numarr=9)</sup>

In rete si possono trovare molte immagini e documentazione, anche se vari siti sono di “lugubri” nostalgici.

(A proposito del frac, aggiungo, anche se qui è di interesse solo marginale, che quando nel 1938 Enrico Fermi ritirò a Stoccolma il premio Nobel per la fisica, i giornali italiani lo criticarono perché indossava il frac anziché un'uniforme, nel suo caso quella dell'Accademia d'Italia. Ma in realtà, anche se non si sapeva, Fermi aveva già rotto col regime: da Stoccolma ripartì con la famiglia direttamente alla volta degli Stati Uniti.)